# Question disappeared from the Front Page

Tags: discussion, support, moderators

One hour after posting this question:[Are Firearm Registries & Firearm Owner Registries Unconstitutional?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42709/are-firearm-registries-firearm-owner-registries-unconstitutional) On a controversial topic, the question has disappeared from even the "Active" tab on the front page of Politics SE. Despite receiving numerous answers and comments within the last few minutes.

What happened? This seems like a deliberate suppression by an unhappy moderator of an unpopular political question, which is ironic since Politics SE should be a haven for all kinds of political questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any question that is downvoted to -4 or worse is automatically hidden from the front page, with the assumption being that the question is low-quality and therefore should be hidden. This is an automated process and *not* something the moderators have any control over.

I'm not going to go into why you may have been downvoted - having read through your question, plenty of explanations have already been given in the comments - but suffice it to say that you are **not** being downvoted for your opinion, only the way in which you (appear to be) expressing it.

You've stated in comments that you're asking this question in good faith, in which case, the best-case scenario is probably for the question to be re-worded in a way that retains the core of your argument but is still neutral, something like the also-controversial (yet now highly-upvoted) [whaling question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/42635/20220). Hopefully then it will start receiving upvotes and higher-quality answers, and get back on the frontpage.

Comment: Didnt know that, thanks. The same comment about the sad state of this stack which apparently rejects unpopular political questions still applies.